# How to check if a point is inside specified area?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, dictionary

my server receive 4 points on the map(a,b,c,d),that represent a rectangle on the map.
in my database I have this business table:

```
bussId | longitude | latitude 
=============================
  ..       ..          ..
```

How could I get the businesses which placed inside the rectangle ?

Answer (score 1):

Let the point be p. p is inside the rectangle with vertices (a,b,c,d) [in order] if and only if the dot product of vectors ab.ap , bc.bp, cd.cp, and da.dp having the same sign (i.e. either they're all positive or all negative). This is only an approximate if you're talking about longitude and latitude because the surface of the Earth is a curved surface, not flat rectangle.